# Google Maps using WebGL in Firefox crashes Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, firefox, webgl

My system configuration (Hp pavilion 15 - p238nd):

- processor: Intel i5-5200U
- graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5500
- Video card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 840M
- Window manager: XMonad

Description of problem:

- Opening Google Maps in Firefox causes all text to disappear from all programs system wide. My xmobar status bar disappears completely. The disappearing is not instantaneous: some text only disappears when the program it is in gets focus. The system is rendered unusable and can only be shut down by blind-typing in a new terminal window. XMonad and dmenu both remain fully functional. Important to note: the text in dmenu does *not* disappear.
- Disabling WebGL in Firefox solves this problem completely.
- Using Google Chrome makes all text flicker, about once every 10 seconds.

Any ideas on the why this happens and how to fix it?